# Saving R Shiny app as a function with arguments passed to the shiny app

Tags: r, function, shiny, arguments, global-variables

I am building an R package that has a function to launch a shiny app. I would like that function to include an argument to be passed to the app. The only way I found to work is setting a global value, and then having the app use that global value:

```
launch_app <- function(MonteCarlo=1000){
  MonteCarlo_global <<- MonteCarlo
  shiny::runApp(appDir = system.file("app.R", package="my_package"))
}
```

Is there a better way to pass my "MonteCarlo" argument to be used throughout the shiny app? Please note I'm trying to avoid simply including "MonteCarlo" as one of the input options within the app itself. I'd rather have the user not worry about it. But, if desired the knowledgeable user can control it when launching the app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I currently use `shinyOptions` and `getShinyOption` to pass arguments to shiny apps.

Also, I `source` the output from `shinyApp` directly rather than unsing `runApp` like so

```
## file: R/launch_app.R
launch_app <- function(MonteCarlo = 1000){
  shinyOptions(MonteCarlo = MonteCarlo)
  source(system.file("app.R", package = "my_pkg", local = TRUE, chdir = TRUE))$value    
}
```

The file `app.R` can look similar to this

```
## file: inst/app.R
appDir <- getwd()
monte.carlo.default <- 1000
MonteCarlo <- getShinyOption("MonteCarlo", monte.carlo.default)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(paste("Chosen parameter:", MonteCarlo)),
  server = function(input, output, session){
     oldwd <- setwd(appDir)
     on.exit(setwd(oldwd))
     ## put more server logic here
  }
)
```

The `setwd()` part is only relevant if you are using local paths inside your `server`.

[Here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/440) you can also find the opinion of the creator of `shiny`, Joe Cheng, about this topic.

### Edit: Why use source instead of runApp?

You are right, the "standard" way is to use `runApp`, but there are two reasons I chose not to do that:

First, `runApp` will save all `server` variables in the global environment. This means that after the app has been stopped, the users of your package will have variables in their workspace that they don't need. If you use the the design I outlined, your user's environments will not be affected by running the app.

Second, by writing your `launch_app` function like this you can easily deploy apps via `shiny-server` like so

```
## file: /srv/shiny-server/my-pkg/app.R
my_pkg::lauch_app(MonteCarlo = 800)
```

whch is not possible if `launch_app` invokes `runApp`. With the `runApp` approach you need to use a symbolic link to the app folder instead which will lead to more maintenance work (for example, if `.libPaths` or the structure of `inst/` changes). Also, you won't be able to pass parameters to the `shiny-server` version of your app as easily

Comment: This worked perfectly -- thank you! I'm curious as to why you source the shiny app output instead of using runApp? It seems like the "standard" way is as outlined [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/deployment-local.html#package)

Comment: You are very welcome. I just edited my answer to explain why I prefer not to use `runApp`.

Comment: @GregordeCillia could you help with the similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57699276/how-to-pass-argument-to-shiny-app-from-run-function