# Is there a way to make my shiny app accept passing of arguments from users?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have got R shiny app that I coded in R studio with separate ui.R, server.R, global.R, and a www folder with some pictures in it. What the app does is that it displays the images from a directory specified in its global.R file. The images have checkboxes allowing user to select images. Once users select their pictures and press the action button called "Create", the app creates 2 text files listing the filenames of the images selected and not selected by user in the app directory.

Now, what I would really need help with are 2 things:

1. Instead of specifying the images directory and the project name in the global.R file, I would like to make my app accept arguments from users, i.e., I would like the users to, somehow when running the app, specify the images directory and the project name (name to be used later in creating the text files). Ideally, I would like to make my global.R file blank, with no code in it. Is that possible? One friend of my mine is suggesting I can use something called ShinyOptions and getShinyOtion but neither me nor he are familiar with that.
2. If I am to run the app from the command line (terminal) of my computer (not the terminal in Rstudio), what do I need to do?

So, if anyone has an idea using those or others would really appreciate their help.

To help reproduce my case, below I am including the code I currently have in my ui.R, server.R, and global.R.

ui

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Pictures List"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    actionButton("the_action_button", "Create", width = "100%")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(
        title = "Picture Selection",
        width = 12,
        uiOutput("image_selection")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

server

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Get a list of available image files from the specified folder
  
  image_files <- list.files(image_folder, pattern = "\\.png$", full.names = FALSE)
  
  # Initialize a list to store selected images
  selected_images <- reactiveVal(character(0))
  
  # Render UI for image selection
  output$image_selection <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      lapply(image_files, function(img) {
        img_tag <- tags$img(src = img, width = "100%")
        checkbox_tag <- checkboxInput(
          inputId = img,
          label = NULL,
          value = img %in% selected_images()
        )
        div(img_tag, checkbox_tag)
      })
    )
  })
  
  # Create and download text files based on selected images
  observeEvent(input$the_action_button, {
    # Create a timestamp for the filenames
    timestamp <- format(Sys.time(), format = "%Y%m%d")
    
    # Create text file for images not selected
    not_selected_images <- setdiff(image_files, selected_images())
    not_selected_filename <- paste0("not_selected_file_", project_name,
                                    "_", timestamp, ".txt")
    writeLines(not_selected_images, con = not_selected_filename)
    
    # Create text file for selected images
    selected_images <- selected_images()
    selected_filename <- paste0("selected_file_list_", project_name, 
                                "_", timestamp, ".txt")
    writeLines(selected_images, con = selected_filename)
  })
}
```

global

```
image_folder <- "~/Desktop/pictures_folder"
project_name <- "land_project"
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but why not just add two `textInput` to the UI?

Comment: @smartse thanks for your reply, you are right that's one possibility but that's not my preference. I am looking for ways of passing that as argument before start of the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think that `shinyOptions` solution is more elegant, if we don't want to use `getShinyOption` I propose doing the following:

- Pass the paths as an argument and assign them to the global environment so the app can reach them.
- Remove variables assigned after the function finished executing with `on.exit`

```r
my_app <- function(image_folder = "~/Desktop/pictures_folder",
                   project_name = "land_project") {
    image_folder <<- image_folder
    project_name <<- project_name
    on.exit({
        rm(list = c("image_folder", "project_name"), envir = .GlobalEnv)
        message("clearing image_folder variable")
    })
    shiny::runApp()
}

my_app()
```

Comment: thanks a lot, your solution worked. 

I ended up copying the my_app function you created into the project-specific .Rprofile file, so that every time R starts in that project, the function can be available. And then finally I can easily start my app by calling the function my_app() from my Rstudio console

Answer (score 1):

So this is really a duplicate of [Saving R Shiny app as a function with arguments passed to the shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470474/saving-r-shiny-app-as-a-function-with-arguments-passed-to-the-shiny-app) and you were on the right track with `shinyOptions` but now that I've figured it out:

You need to launch the app with a function which calls `shiny::runApp` (there are various options for what you pass this in order to find the server and ui).

```
run_app <- function(image_folder,project_name){
shinyOptions(image_folder = image_folder)
shinyOptions(project_name = project_name)
shiny::runApp("<location of ui.R and server.R>")
}
```

Then in the server add this (I only tried outside of the main function, but it shouldn't matter if it's inside):

```
image_folder <- getShinyOption("image_folder", image_folder.default)
project_name <- getShinyOption("project_name", project_name.default)
```

And then to launch the app use:

```
run_app("~/Desktop/pictures_folder","land_project")
```

Comment: Thanks @smartse, I think this going to work but one question before I go ahead implement that, where do I need to place (server.R or ui.R) the function you wrote which is:

run_app <- function(image_folder,project_name){
shinyOptions(image_folder = image_folder)
shinyOptions(project_name = project_name)
shiny::runApp("<location of ui.R and server.R>")
}

??

Comment: That's a good question! It's difficult to know without knowing more about how your app is going to be distributed, but it can be anywhere so long as it is sourced before you call it. It's easiest if you put it in `R/run_app.R` package the app and then it's sourced when you load the package.

Comment: I tried placing the run_app function in the global.R and tried running it using run_app("~/Desktop/pictures_folder","land_project") as you suggested, but it is not working for me. I am getting the following error

Error in shinyOptions(image_folder = image_folder) : 
  could not find function "shinyOptions"

It seems that it's not finding any such function as "shinyOptions". Are there any libraries I need to load prior to calling that function?Any ideas how I can get that fixed? And please as much detail as you can. Thanks

Comment: I never suggested using global.R - that's a file that is automatically loaded when `shiny::runApp` is called, but you need the function loaded prior to that. `shinyOptions` is part of shiny, so you may need to call `library(shiny)` inside the file with the function in it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Ok if global.R is not where you are suggesting me to put the run_app function, where are you suggesting then? Would appreciate it if you can give me a couple of options.

Comment: I suggested you package the app and put it in `R/run_app.R` but you can just put it in `run_app.R` and source that before calling the function

Answer (score -1):

use Shiny's textInput and fileInput widgets to allow users to specify the image directory and project name when running the app :

```
library(shiny)
```

library(shinydashboard)

dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Pictures List"),
dashboardSidebar(
textInput("image_directory", "Image Directory", placeholder = "Enter directory path"),
textInput("project_name", "Project Name", placeholder = "Enter project name"),
actionButton("the_action_button", "Create", width = "100%")
),
dashboardBody(
fluidRow(
box(
title = "Picture Selection",
width = 12,
uiOutput("image_selection")
)
)
)
)

**update your server.R to use these inputs:**

```
 library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    # Get the image folder and project name from user inputs
    image_folder <- input$image_directory
    project_name <- input$project_name
    
    # Get a list of available image files from the specified folder
    image_files <- list.files(image_folder, pattern = "\\.png$", full.names = FALSE)
    
    # ... rest of your server logic ...
  })

  # ... rest of your server logic ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, I am not looking for ways of taking those information via textinput. I am looking for ways of obtaining that via an argument before users start the app.